# What is the best way to use Flutter provider with a firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I want to update my view on every database change using provider package, the problem is that whenever I use provider to update the view on every database change, it keeps updating the view every second even if there is no changes. What is the best approach to achieve this without updating the view every second

Comment: Provide the code you are using now, that will be helpful to suggest you better approach.
I usually use, StreamProvider from flutter provider package to provide data streams, so it automatically updates when database changes.

Comment: You can follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-statemanagement-with-provider-ee251bbc5ac1) and verify if you're using the provider package correctly. 
As @dlohani said, it'll be helpful if you can provide code in order to look further.

Comment: @dlohani  Thank you so much, using StreamProvider solved the issue

Comment: @NibrassHaider Thanks I will check this tutorial